# how to split log messages into file and screen in wxwidgets

Tags: c++, linux, windows, logging, wxwidgets

When I read the WxWidgets documentation, I get the impression that the developers wrote it just for themselves, just to remember what they did 20 years ago.

Regardless, I figured out how to send log messages to a file:

```
wxLog::SetActiveTarget(new wxLogStderr(fopen(logPath + "/wxApp.log", "w + ")));
```

and also I figured out how to change the format of the log messages:

```
wxLog::GetActiveTarget()->SetFormatter(new MyLogger);
```

But I didn't understand anything else.
So I want to ask my question here.

I want to make a log for my application. 
Moreover, I want:

1. all log messages to be written to a file
2. at the same time some of these messages are displayed on the screen using wxTextCtrl.
   So I want to filter the log messages that are displayed on the screen, depending on the logging level: 
   for example, I want to display in wxTextCtrl only log messages with "wxLOG_Info" and "wxLOG_Error" levels.

How can this be done in Windows and Linux in C++? It's best to show a code example.

Comment: Never used wxWidgets, but the documentation looks pretty nice to me. First, take a look at the main logging class and all available log sinks: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_log.html Now, scan over the names. See something that stands out? To me, `wxLogChain` appears to be what you're looking for. But then, [wxLogWindow](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_log_window.html) _is_ a log chain. So perhaps you just need to override that to do your filtering, and then chain the messages. If filtering isn't built-in. That's what I learned from 2 minutes browsing the docs.

Comment: @paddy, I read this and understood WHAT needs to be done in 1 minute. But I don't understand HOW to do it.

Comment: Yes, wxWidgets documentation is hard to crack, you need some experience and sometimes even check the source code. Although the book on wxWidgets is outdated, it should help to you for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing something but this seems very simple?

For example, this could be the simplest possible log target which logs some messages into a `wxTextCtrl` and all of them into a `wxFFile`.

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/ffile.h>

class MyLogTarget : public wxLog
{
public:
    // textCtrl must have longer lifetime than MyLogTarget
    MyLogTarget(wxTextCtrl* textCtrl, const wxString& fileName)
        : m_textCtrl(textCtrl), m_file(fileName, "a")
    {}
protected:
    void DoLogTextAtLevel(wxLogLevel level, const wxString& msg) override
    {
        // preserve debug logging
        if ( level == wxLOG_Debug || level == wxLOG_Trace )
            wxLog::DoLogTextAtLevel(level, msg);

        if ( level == wxLOG_Info || level == wxLOG_Error )
            m_textCtrl->AppendText(msg + "\n");
        
        if ( m_file.IsOpened() )
            m_file.Write(msg + "\n");
    }
private:
    wxTextCtrl* m_textCtrl;
    wxFFile     m_file;
};

class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(wxWindow* parent = nullptr) : wxFrame(parent, wxID_ANY, "Test")
    {
        wxTextCtrl* logCtrl = new wxTextCtrl(this, wxID_ANY, "", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTE_MULTILINE | wxTE_READONLY | wxTE_RICH2);
        wxLog::SetActiveTarget(new MyLogTarget(logCtrl, "log.txt"));

        wxLogDebug("Debug test");
        wxLogMessage("Message test");
        wxLogInfo("Info test");
        wxLogError("Error test");
    }
    ~MyFrame()
    {
        delete wxLog::SetActiveTarget(nullptr);
    }
};

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    bool OnInit() override
    {
        (new MyFrame())->Show();
        return true;
    }
}; wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

Please notice that this would have to be extended to be usable in a real application, for example, handle the file encoding / flushing / cleaning / error handling (without getting into the endless logging loop), use the full path for the file (e.g., obtained with `wxStandardPaths`), use a log chain to preserve (some of?) the default wxWidgets logging...

If you want to use separate log targets for logging into a text control and a file, it is still very simple except that you have to chain the log targets, as explained in the docs.

Comment: nice example! Thank you. Could you please show me how to use wxLogChain?

Comment: There is nothing to show, using wxLogChain is really as simple as described in its docs at https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_log_chain.html